# Not sure whether I understand certain adjoint impilcation correctly.

Tags: category-theory, definition, adjoint-functors

My textbook:

> The naturality axiom implies that from each array of maps $A_0 \rightarrow... \rightarrow A_n$, $F(A_n) \rightarrow B_0$, $B_0 \rightarrow... \rightarrow B_m$ it is possible to construct **exactly one** map $A_0 \rightarrow G(B_m)$.

$F, G$ are adjoint functors.

> The naturality axiom has two parts: 
>   $$\overline{F(A) \rightarrow B \rightarrow B'} = (A \rightarrow G(B) \rightarrow G(B')$$ 
>   $$\overline{A' \rightarrow A \rightarrow G(B)} = (F(A') \rightarrow F(A) \rightarrow B)$$

Is it because both left part ($A_0 \rightarrow... \rightarrow A_n$) and right part ($B_0 \rightarrow... \rightarrow B_m$) are trivially reduced to $f = A_0 \rightarrow A_n$ and $g = B_0 \rightarrow B_m$ respectively and thus there is only one way to combine $g  \circ F(A_n) \rightarrow B_0 \circ f$?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? I'm assuming $G$ and $F$ are intended to be adjoint, but I'm not sure why arrays of arrows come up, or what this author is referring to by "the naturality axiom". Also, do you mean to use "$\mapsto$", or do you mean "$\to$"?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, thanks for comment, please see updated OP.

Comment: What operations are being used in the construction of $A_0 \to G(B_m)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $F ⊢ G :  → ℬ$ with
    $$fᵢ : Aᵢ → Aᵢ₊₁ ∈ $$
and $$gᵢ : Bᵢ → Bᵢ₊₁ ∈ ℬ$$
and $$m  : F Aₙ → B₀$$

Then we want to construct a map $A₀ → G Bₘ$.

Indeed the transpose of $m$ yields
$$m′ : Aₙ → G B₀$$
and the $G$-lifting of the $gᵢ$ yields
$$G gᵢ : G Bᵢ → G Bᵢ₊₁$$

Hence, $$G gₘ₋₁ ∘ G gₘ₋₂ ∘ G g₀ ∘ ⋯ ∘ m′ : Aₙ → G Bₘ$$
Whence, $$G gₘ₋₁ ∘ G gₘ₋₂ ∘ G g₀ ∘ ⋯ ∘ m′ ∘ fₙ₋₁ ∘ ⋯ f₀ : A₀ → G Bₘ$$

There might be other maps $A₀ → G Bₘ$, but from the given data
I am only able to construct the one above.

Comment: As far as I understand, you demonstrated what I assumed to be true: indeed both left and right sides trivially reduce to a respective maps and thus composition completely determenistic. Thanks.